# Troubleshooting internet connectivity

Tags: internet, troubleshooting, interface

Recently I see that I often lose internet connectivity on my Linux machines. I am starting to think that it may be a router problem, but I have no idea to check if this is indeed the problem.

Basically what happens is that if I type `ifconfig` I get the list of all the interfaces, but none of them have an assigned IP address. Even when I use `dhclient` to pull a random IP address, I still am not able to ping or surf the web.

This is an example of `ifconfig` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:b3:da:a1  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feb3:daa1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1351 (1.3 KB)  TX bytes:6466 (6.4 KB)
```

How can I troubleshoot internet connectivity issues? What files do I have to look at?

Comment: Are you using IPv6 on your LAN? That interface output shows an IPv6 address but no IPv4 address.

Comment: @Tim that's right, but I am not using IPv6. I have a Windows machine that uses IPv4 and doesn't have any connectivity problems.

Comment: If the ifconfig output you have listed above is what shows right after you have run dhclient then I would suspect something is wrong with your DHCP server. If DHCP is provided by the router, then try disabling IPv6 support. You could also just try a static IP to determine the source of the problem being DHCP.

Comment: @Tim for example, now I rebooted the router and I see that a machine has successfully pulled an IP address and Internet connectivity is working. How can I check if DHCP is indeed the problem?

Comment: Lookup how to set a static IP for your distro. Once it is setup and ou reboot or restart networking, wait for a while to see if you have the same intermittent problems with a static IP. If the problems do not arise then it is certainly DHCP being weird.

Comment: @Tim the same thing happens intermittently also when I set a static IP...

Comment: Sounds like bad cable, bad network card, or bad port that it is plugged into on the router or the router all together. Now you must perform much more involved troubleshooting. Try a new cable, new card and new router... You can build a linux router if money is too tight for a new router, but that's a different topic ;)

Comment: Also check for any errors in the kernel log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering with the configuration files I have found out that the problem often involved the routing table. After configuring the route manually the problem was solved.

```
route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```